# What app has this blue penguin in the Social category?

Tags: ios, applications

Could someone identify what the app with the blue penguin is?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It’s TweetCaster Pro for Twitter.
[image: TwwetCaster]

Answer (score 0):

Looks like [TweetCaster for Twitter](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tweetcaster-for-twitter/id420792544).